# Sharing a static button between two Android Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

If  create a static button in one activity  and use in another activity it shows error as

> 01-12 19:57:17.030: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(21860): 
>       couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2f5671b8 has no id.

My code is:

```
public static LoginButton bttn;
  findViewById(R.id.login).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bttn = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login);

    startActivity(new Intent(Account.this,Example.class));

   }

  });
```

In the second activity I use this static button as

```
Account.bttn.init(this, mFacebook);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `public void onClick(View v)`, try adding `if (v.getId() == R.id.your_button_id)`. This way, Android knows that the onClick handler relates to your button click.

Update: try

```
Button bttn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
bttn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) { 
        startActivity(new Intent(Account.this,Example.class));
    }

});
```

It should be more or less like this. Are you sure there is such thing as a `LoginButton` ?

Comment: thanks for ur reply..Its not working..Pls give me alternatives

Comment: @Venkatesh. Need more information. Please attach your log file !

Comment: Oops. I just re-read your "properly-fixed" code. See my other answer.

Comment: Did you call setContentView, before calling findViewById? It returns null until that.